# How to disable warnings in only one project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I have a legacy project in my solution without comments and many warnings. I want to not see warnings about this specific project but I want to see warnings of the other projects in the same solution.

Is it possible?

edit:
I mean "all warnings" of specific project.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. In Visual Studio open the project's Properties tab
2. Go to the "Build" tab
3. Set the "Warning Level" to 0

For details on the different warning levels see:

[C# Compiler Options > /warn (Specify Warning Level)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/warn-compiler-option)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Sorry @lazyberezovsky I think this answer was the first.

Comment: For Visual C++ 2010: Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Warning Level

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 6):

Open project properties.
Build > Errors and warnings > Warning level

Select `0` warning level.
Details you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Is the Link dead?

Answer (score 4):

Open the Properties of the project and go to the Build page.
Here you will find the Error & Warnings input box
Put the warning number to hide in the input box **without the first two letters**
If you have more than one warning separate them with colon or semi-colon

(Sorry if labels are not precise, I'm translating from another language VS)

Comment: Not exaclty this. I want to hide all of them. But only one project.

Answer (score 1):

Each project in Visual Studio has a "treat warnings as errors" option. Go through each of your projects and change that setting:

1. Right-click on your project, select "Properties".
2. Click "Build".
3. Switch "Treat warnings as errors" from "All" to "Specific warnings"
       or "None".