# Supress warnings in Visual Studio for a specific project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable warnings in only one project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983759/how-to-disable-warnings-in-only-one-project)

I want to disable all warnings of a project in a Visual Studio solution (.NET) since the code inside this project is not production relevant and only contains demo code for using internal APIs.

Do I have any chance to do this globally (without entering a pragma in each and every file?)

Thanks.

Comment: yes, I close it; have not seen the duplicate, thx!